How do I decrease the opacity of the page background without decreasing text opacity?
I'm pretty new and am trying to make a webpage. I wish to decrease the opacity of the bg image.
I want the page background opacity to be pretty low, but since the bg image is in the body element (CSS), the opacity of other items in the body also decreases.
body {
    background-image: url(robot_movement_street_1306245_1920x1080.jpg); 
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

